# BigQuery JSON element extraction

Tags: json, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have a table in BigQuery with a JSON column, see below.

| doc_id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 222 | {...} |
| 333 | {...} |

The data JSON column looks like the IDs are set as headers.

```
{
    "1675223776617": {
        "author": "aaa",
        "new": "2023-02-01",
        "old": null,
        "property": "asd",
        "sender": "wew"
    },
    "1675223776618": {
        "author": "aaa",
        "new": true,
        "old": null,
        "property": "asd",
        "sender": "ewew"
    },
    "1675223776619": {
        "author": "bbb",
        "new": "ySk2btk7",
        "old": null,
        "property": "qwe",
        "sender": "yyy"
    }
}
```

I would like to extract this JSON into this format using SQL in BigQuery.

> Note, the header `id` isn't defined in the JSON.

| doc_id | id | author | new | old | property | sender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | 1675223776617 | aaa | 2023-02-01 | null | asd | wew |
| 222 | 1675223776618 | aaa | true | null | asd | ewew |
| 222 | 1675223776619 | bbb | ySk2btk7 | null | qwe | yyy |

I tried using the JSON_EXTRACT function without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider below approach using javascript UDF.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION flatten_json(json STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<id STRING, author STRING, new STRING, old STRING, property STRING, sender STRING>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  result = [];
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(JSON.parse(json))) {
    value["id"] = key; result.push(value);
  }
  return result;
""";

WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 222 doc_id, '''{
    "1675223776617": {
        "author": "aaa",
        "new": "2023-02-01",
        "old": null,
        "property": "asd",
        "sender": "wew"
    },
    "1675223776618": {
        "author": "aaa",
        "new": true,
        "old": null,
        "property": "asd",
        "sender": "ewew"
    },
    "1675223776619": {
        "author": "bbb",
        "new": "ySk2btk7",
        "old": null,
        "property": "qwe",
        "sender": "yyy"
    }
  }''' data
)
SELECT doc_id, flattened.*
  FROM sample_table, UNNEST(flatten_json(json)) flattened;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Thanks!
The only thing I needed to change to make it work was to point to the `data` column in the function and to include the `doc_id` in the `SELECT`.


`SELECT doc_id, flattened.*
FROM sample_table, UNNEST(flatten_json(data)) flattened`